# Extract RapidMiner Linear Regression Model Coefficients

Tags: rapidminer

I would like to run a simulation that depends upon Linear Regression Model coefficients.

In RapidMiner, how could I extract the Linear Regression Model coefficients?

I would find it very useful if I could get those coefficients into macro parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's mildly clunky but it is possible to export the model to a PMML file, read it back in and then parse it using XPath.

There's an example using decision trees at this [link](http://rapidminernotes.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/how-to-read-pmml-file-to-determine.html).

Answer (score 0):

The recently released *Converters Extensions*, available at the RapidMiner marketplace, has an Operator for this.
Take a look at the Linear "Regression Model to ExampleSet", it will return the coefficients as an ExampleSet.